# Powershell equivalent of 'msconfig'?

Tags: powershell, msconfig

I use 'msconfig' to control what programs startup at boot (etc) - is there a powershell way of doing the same ?

I tried:

```
get-help startup
```

This brings up:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration
Get-PSSessionConfiguration     
Set-PSSessionConfiguration     
Enable-PSRemoting              
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile 
New-Service                    
Set-Service                    
Set-WmiInstance                
about_PowerShell.exe           
about_Remote_FAQ               
about_Remote_Troubleshooting   
about_Windows_RT               
about_WS-Management_Cmdlets
```

I just wanted a Powershell list which is the equivalent of what is shown in the 'msconfig.exe' ("System Configuration") Startup tab.

I'm on Windows 7, with Powershell 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built-in functionality, but you can use [AutoRuns module](https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/first-release-of-autoruns-module/):

> AutoRuns is a module that will help do live incident response and
>   enumerate autoruns artifacts that may be used by legitimate programs
>   as well as malware to achieve persistence

Comment: Thanks ! Slightly odd marketing to include it's 'dark-side' malware-ready credentials though :-\

Comment: or did you mean that 'AutoRuns' is good at *detecting* certain classes of malware !? Rather than being a good tool to write malware with ? !

Comment: @monojohnny `AutoRuns` module provides PowerShell implemenation of  [SysInternal's Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) functionality. Since it's author is interested in malware research and forensics, he also added some related functionality (like PoweLiks malware detection).